# Understanding directional derivative in a example

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

> Prove that the directional derivatives of
> $$
> f(x, y)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
> \frac{x^{2} y}{x^{4}+y^{2}} & (x, y) \neq(0,0) \\
> 0 & (x, y)=(0,0)
> \end{array}\right.
> $$
> exist at $(0,0)$ in all directions $\boldsymbol{u},$ but $f$ is neither continuous nor differentiable
> at $(0,0)$

Proof. Let $(u, v)$ be a unit vector. By definition,
$$
D_{(u, v)} f(0,0)=\lim _{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(t u, t v)-f(0,0)}{t}=\lim _{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{u^{2} v}{u^{4} t^{2}+v^{2}}=\left\{\begin{array}{lr}
u^{2} / v & v \neq 0 \\
0 & v=0
\end{array}\right.
$$
Thus the directional derivatives of $f$ exist. On the other hand, $f$ is not continuous because along the path $x=0$ the limit is zero, but along the path $y=x^{2}$ the limit is $1 / 2$

**My question is** Why did we say that  "if $v\neq 0$ and $v=0 $" in the above piecewise function, I couldn't understand. Where is this coming from? Can you explain it? Why didn't we say $(u,v)\neq (0,0)$ or $(u,v)=(0,0)$ above piecewise function? Thanks...

Comment: Do you agree with $\lim _{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{u^{2} v}{u^{4} t^{2}+v^{2}}$ ? Then you see that if $v=0$, this is always $0$ ; and if $v \neq 0$, this converges to $\frac{u^2v}{v^2} = \frac{u^2}{v}$. It is just the two cases appearing when you compute the limit.

Comment: You have $u^4t^2+v^2$ in a denominator. As $t\to 0$, it tends to $v^2$. The eleventh commandment is **thou shalt not divide by zero**. So you realise that when $v\ne0$ there is nothing to worry about, but when $v=0$ you need to tread carefully.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Ahh okayyy. I understood.

Comment: @AnginaSeng Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $(u,v)=(0,0)$ is not possible, since $(u,v)$ is a unit vector.
2. for $v \ne 0$ we have

$$ \frac{u^{2} v}{u^{4} t^{2}+v^{2}} \to \frac{u^{2} v}{v^{2}}= \frac{u^{2}}{ v}$$

as $t \to 0.$

3. for $v=0$ we have $$ \frac{u^{2} v}{u^{4} t^{2}+v^{2}}=0.$$

Answer (score 1):

The denominator $u^4t^2+v^2$ goes to $v^2$ when $t\to0$. If $v=0$ it converges to $0$, and $0$ is a critical value with respect to a limit if it is present in the denominator.